# Reading and writing every 100 rows of an xlsx file using Python3.x

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

There is an xlsx file with one column with url. The number of rows is undefined. We need to read from the file every 100 rows and send them to write in .txt file until the rows run out. The last iteration can be less than 100 rows. I only figured out to send the first 100 rows and I don't understand the rest. I use openpyxl.

Example sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16qietXcZbGEKCyVxBMuN1PRG2Xlp7I_xIi7mYIuWSHg/edit#gid=0

I know there is isslice() and itertools.groupby() but I don't understand how to use them. Here is a part of code, which reads and writes first 100 rows.

```
import datetime
from openpyxl import load_workbook

a_file = load_workbook("urls.xlsx") # get file
a_sheet = a_file["Sheet1"] # get sheet 

def write_result(work_type, url, date): 
    if work_type == 'txt_file':
        with open('result.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as result_file:
            string_write = f"{url};{date}\n"
            result_file.write(string_write)  # write url to text file

def send_urls():
    row_num = 2
    for rows in a_sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=100, max_col=1):
        for url in rows:
            if url.value is not None:
                url_new = str(a_sheet.cell(column=1, row=row_num).value).strip()
                write_result('txt_file', url_new, datetime.date.today())
                row_num += 1
    a_file.save("urls.xlsx")
    a_file.close()

def main():
    send_urls()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Check `pandas.read_excel`, it has `skiprows` and `nrows` arguments that is what you are looking for. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html If you share your excel file I can make an example ad hoc.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, what is `a_sheet`? How can you have it in your function without passing it? Is it a global? Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: how about `df[i: i+100]` inside `for i in range(0, len(df), 100):`

Comment: @alec_djinn thanks for the correction, I added some of the code

Comment: There is another point that is not fully clear. Do you want the output file to be closed every 100 lines? Or it is only the input file that should read in batches of 100 lines?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using `pandas` (you also need `openpyxl`)

```
import pandas as pd

skiprows = 1 #skip header line
nrows = 100
infile = 'urls.xlsx'
outfile = 'urls.txt'

with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
    while True:
        df = pd.read_excel(infile, skiprows=skiprows, nrows=nrows, header=None)
        if len(df) == 0: break #if there is no data left to read, break the loop

        skiprows += nrows #update for the next loop cycle
        urls = df[0].values #if there is no header, the column is called 0 by default
        f.write('\n'.join(urls) + '\n')
```

It is not fully clear from your question if you want to close the output file after every chunks. I just opened the file in write mode before the loop and I keep it open until the end. In case, you can open it in append mode inside the loop body, but I don't see the advantage of doing that.